# Насколько приемлено использовать везде auto вместо явного определения?

Tags: c++, c++11, переменные, auto

Я везде где только можно использую auto вместо явного определения переменных, возврата значений, и.т.д. Насколько это плохо, и стоит ли так делать?

Считается ли это плохим стилем программирования?

Comment: *С моей точки зрения* избыточное применение `auto` затрудняет восприятие/понимание кода..

Comment: Следует использовать не *везде где только можно*, а там, где есть тип зависит от инициализатора. Т.е. надо четко различать сценарии, где тип совпадает с типом инициализатора, но не зависит от него, и использовать в них явное указание типа.

Comment: Во первых, в ООП нет переменных, а есть объекты.  Если  тип объекта  не  существенен при объявлении и  для  его дальнейшего использования, и  явно  не очевиден (вместо того, чтобы написать  TYPE A не стоить прибегать к auto\ , имеет   сложное, длинное имя, стоит с помощью auto это выразить. Кроме того читайте предыдущие комментария...

Comment: Полностью согласен с @Harry